# Mystery Mostek part

Tags: identification

Can anyone help identify this Mostek part please? Have checked all the Mostek catalogues I could find without success.

[image]

Comment: Based on what appear to be the power pins, and pins 8-9 ans pins 13-14 connected together, I suspect it's a quad opamp.

Comment: Questions like this are at best marginally on topic.  While it's great that you've provided a close up photo, you also need to describe the nature of the equipment and provide a larger photo giving the perspective of this part's role in the board overall.

Comment: @brhans - I think you're right - but I can't find any reference to the part.

Comment: @Chris Stratton - it's associated with a LCD graphics controller and row/column drivers - so probably a voltage level driver. A quad opamp would make sense.